# Error: Map container not found. with leaflet map using Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, leaflet, mapbox

Full error:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Map container not found.
    at NewClass._initContainer (leaflet-src.js:4066)
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js:3099)
    at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:296)
    at Object.createMap [as map] (leaflet-src.js:4691)
    at MapViewComponent.ngAfterViewInit (map-view.component.ts:13)
    at callHook (core.js:2526)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
    at refreshView (core.js:9536)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10590)
```

I get this whenever I try to load the component that contains the map. Here is the .ts file
(I hid the access token)

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-view',
  templateUrl: './map-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-view.component.scss'],
})
export class MapViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution:
        'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: 'my.token',
    }).addTo(mymap);
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

and .css file

```
#map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

It's really a simple map I'm just following the quickstart guide on their site but it's not working. I've already tried with ngOnInit and it's the same thing. Also added leaflet to angular.json. I tried changing the order of the lines in the .html file, placing the map div in all 3 possible places and it's the same error.

Comment: Hey have you ever found the solution? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Noob if I remember correctly, the problem was outside of this class and it had to do with the order in which we loaded the components.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-and-leaflet)

Take a look at my [implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oyqwis?file=angular.json)

Comment: I've already tried this example and it didn't work either

Comment: @MoroAstray Please take a look at the link I have provided

Comment: Thank you, I've done everything like you but it seems that something else in my project is causing the problem. Can I ask where did you put the leaflet link and script tags in your project?

Comment: @MoroAstray Sure. I've added leaflet as a dependency https://monosnap.com/file/scEaviH1RkXSWjJ5I4CMlcfCK9K8l0 and imported one into the map.component.ts. I didn't add js scripts, only added CSS file in angular.json

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried putting a leaflet map in an Angular Material Tab component. The problem was that leaflet was trying to initialize the map but the dom wasn't loaded yet. What fixed it was implementing lazy loading by declaring the body of the tab in a ng-template with the matTabContent attribute. It looks like this:

```
<mat-tab-group preserveContent>
  <mat-tab label="Home">
     <app-home></app-home>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Applications">
    <app-applications></app-applications>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Map">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-map></app-map>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to add link and script tags in component html file. Add these links in application index.html

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin="" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
</body>
```

Component.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Component.ts

```
declare const L: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after trying this